# How do I re-use the same control twice but keep state between them

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a control which I need to use twice in an Options dialog, but I need to somehow keep and know the state of each control. The control has a few checkboxes, and some "entity" has to know which of those are checked in which control.

I tried 2 approaches - having each control have its own VM and also having one VM being used by both. The latter approach doesn't make sense to me - I have a grid visibility bound to a property on the VM -- so which grid will be disabled? The one on Control A or Control B? The former approach (each control having its own VM) works for that UI matter, but I need some class to be able to know about each controls state.

I thought of having a VM for each but have them share a model? So pass the same Model for both, and it would be the Model who will keep the state of both? But is it acceptable, as far as MVVM approach, for the model to take that kind of responsibility?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: what do you mean by "I need some class to be able to know about each controls state"? does the state of control A effects control B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'state' of an application, or particular view/form/window comes from the data. In MVVM, the state typically comes from the view model. Therefore, to share state between two (or more) windows/controls/views/etc., you simply need to share the data.

One possibility would be to share the same view model and another would be to 'clone' the view model, eg. share a copy of the view model. However, from your description, it seems that your view model has properties *not* considered to be 'data'.

Therefore, it makes sense to create a class that contains all of the properties that you call 'data'. Then it is a simple matter of creating a property of that new class type in both of your separate view models and data bind to the same object. Take this simple example:

In both view models:

```
public YourNewDataType Model
{
    get { return model; }
    set { if (value != model) { model = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Model"); } }
}
```

Initialising view models:

```
viewModel1.Model = viewModel2.Model = new YourNewDataType();
```

Data binding in views:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Model.SomePropertyInYourNewDataType}" ... />
```

Comment: Thanks Sheridan - so basically what I was thinking (having the "model" to be that shared class between the VM's). I already have a model that takes care of the actual "data", but didn't feel too comfortable having it also keep state that would naturally live in the VM. But seems like I don't have too many other options here.